# remote: You need 'Push' rights to upload code review requests

Tags: git

I added the following in .git/config file to change the default username and email as below but when I try to do a git push,it complains about "remote: User: adavid",i have no idea where this user is coming from?any idea why is this happening and how to fix it?

.git/config

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
[remote "quic"]
        url = git://git-android.quicinc.com/kernel/msm
        review = review-android.quicinc.com
        projectname = kernel/msm
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/quic/*
[user]
        name = Aaaron David
    email = aaroond@codeaurora.org
```

Error:-

```
terminal{243}> git push
```

Comment: please show your git config

Comment: @fix - Updated the git config

Comment: `adavid` is probably your ssh username

Comment: @RC - yes,its my noncodeaurora userid but why is git seeing this userid when I clearly mentioned to pick aaroond@codeaurora.org in .git/config

Answer (score 1):

I think adavid is your local system user and it's used by underlying ssh to push changes.

Set your `$HOME/.ssh/config`:

```
host review-android.quicinc.com
    Port 29418
    User aaroond@codeaurora.org
```

I'm not sure how to ssh handles the host:port situation. pushing to just `ssh://review-android.quicinc.com/kernel/msm` should work now.

Comment: @fix - id ont see any .ssh/config in my directory

Comment: it's in your $HOME, it might be empty or nonexisting anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure how ssh handles usernames with @, maybe your remote system only want's to see the aaroond part as username. Btw: `man ssh_config` will show you all details of that config file.

Comment: @fix - if i do the above,am getting an error "Bad owner or permissions on /usr2/adavid/.ssh/config"

Comment: yeah. run `chmod 600 $HOME/.ssh/config; chmod 700 $HOME/.ssh`. only you should be allowed to see that file.